# jquery on click replace with another image

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

when i click the add image div i should replace the current image with another cross image with back ground white

can you tell me how to accomplish it... : http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/11/

cross image https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7ReWpack5aWmdLSmc/edit

```
$("div").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<div>add image</div>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: You know, the other panes are there for a reason.  At least separate your js, html, and css.

Comment: This `$(this).find("div:last").remove();` looks very fragile.

Comment: This is how your fiddle should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/9b7rS/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/13/

is this what u want ?

Comment: The initial image is of a different size than the one you want to replace it with. Do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @user1471711 "when i click the _add image_ div"

Comment: @user1471711 note that `live` is outdated and `on` should be used instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply...the click should work for only this <div>add image</div> not the entire image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".container").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/m7_Lya1KfrYkW1_i1ZyiTrDu6xazZzfvEvG2I6vS7L66QMYQhbhfDxw5SGLu6o-7d5q0y8HY-zVyudf2');                         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way will be changing of `src` attribute of the child `<img>` of the the `<div>`:

```
$("div").hover(
    ....
).click(function() {
    $(this).children("img").attr("src", "newUrl");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/15/

**UPDATED**: If you want to change the image on click on the "Add image" div you can use the following code

```
$("div").hover(
  function () {
    $("<div>add image</div>").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children("img").attr("src", "newUrl");
    }).appendTo(this);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
  }
);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/20/

Comment: thanks for your reply...the click should work for only this <div>add image</div> not the entire image

Comment: when the new image comes in the <div>add image</div> should dissappear

Comment: @user1781238: then you can just insert `$(this).remove();` inside of `click` handler: http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/21/

Comment: @user1781238: You need just call `unbind("hover")` on the `<div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/23/